# my ipod classic 160gb is not recognised in my computer when connected but is still charging

Tags: ipod-classic

My Ipod Classic 160gb is not being recognised in my computer or itunes when connected but is still charging. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to the site. I can only provide the most general answer that yes, things can be done to fix your issue. The first would be to [edit in some details](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on what OS your computer runs and perhaps what version of iTunes and if you are looking at any guide or help article from Apple to troubleshoot this. That allows us to help with whatever item you are stuck on without going into things too basic or too advanced for where you are in troubleshooting this.

Comment: The [help] is in the link to the left and a potential article you might consult could be http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1496

Answer (score 1):

There are a whole host of things that can cause the software chain to not recognize an iPod and/or iOS device.